# Why can't I start KVM when using RDP?

Tags: kvm, qemu, xrdp, rdp

I can run KVM locally fine, but if I connect via RDP (tried via a Windows computer and a chromebook) I get the following error.

`Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize kvm: Permission denied`

Why can't I start KVM over RDP? Do I have a different role or access level when using RDP?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have a different role or access level when using RDP?

Yes, when you use RDP your session isn’t identified as a local console, so you don’t get automatic access to devices managed by `udev` using the `uaccess` system (audio etc., including KVM).

To access KVM in an RDP session, you’ll have to add yourself to the `kvm` group.